# c++ function overloading, expression templates and namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, overloading, expression-templates

I'm developing an automatic differentiation tool based on expression templates and operator/function overloading. The template *std::max* function, for example, was successfully overloaded:

```
namespace ead {
    ...
    template<class A>
    struct ExprWrap
    {
        inline
        operator A const& () const
        { return *static_cast<A const*>(this);}
    };

    class adnumber : public ExprWrap<adnumber>
    { ..... };

    template<typename L, typename R>
    class MaxExpr : public ExprWrap<MaxExpr<L,R> >{ ...... };

    // overloading std::max
    template<typename L, typename R>
    MaxExpr<L,R>
    max (ExprWrap<L> const& l, ExprWrap<R> const& r)
    {
        return MaxExpr<L,R>(l,r); // return an expression
    }
    ...
}
```

but in a code like the following

```
using namespace std;
using namespace ead;

adnumber x,y,z;
z = max(x,y);      // call std::max
```

*std::* is used if the namespace is omitted, and for some other functions, *ead::* is used. Is there a trick to force the compiler to always choose the ead:: namespace, for example, for max function? (without C++11 features, please) Why compiler thinks the std::max is a better match?
Ok, I know that to write *ead::* before functions name is not a big deal, but I'd like to save the user from typing.

Comment: In which namespace is `adnumber` defined?

Comment: What is the exact type of `adnumber`? Does it inherit from `ExprWrapper`?

Comment: @pmr,yes, ExprWrapper is a CRTP. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what instantiation of `std::max` yields:

```
std::max(ead::adnumber, ead::number);
```

This is a better match than your signature of `max` (it is an exact match). Thus it will be called. Your only way out is to qualify the call, because you cannot make instantiation of `std::max` fail through SFINAE or make your `ead::max` a fully generic `ead::max(T, T)` as well. The second attempt would make the call ambiguous.

Comment: ok, I get it ... if it is the only way, I will not waste my time looking for another, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `adnumber` is a user defined type (i.e., **not** a `typedef`) defined in namespace `ead`, the function `max()` should be searched namespaces `ead` and `std`. Of course, `std::max()` is a perfect match, i.e., it wins overload resolution unless `adnumber` happens to be a `typedef` for `ExprWrap<T>` for some type `T`. Here is a boiled down example showing the different cases:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace ead
{
    template <typename T> struct ExprWrap {};

    template <typename T>
    void max(ExprWrap<T> const&) { std::cout << "ead::max()\n"; }

    typedef int builtin;
    struct other {};
    typedef ExprWrap<int> instance;
    struct derived: ExprWrap<int> {};
}

namespace foo
{
    template <typename T>
    void max(T const&) { std::cout << "foo::max()\n"; }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace foo;
    using namespace ead;

    ead::builtin  b;
    ead::other    o;
    ead::instance i;
    ead::derived  d;

    max(b);
    max(o);
    max(i);
    max(d);
}
```

This should print

```
foo::max()
foo::max()
ead::max()
foo::max()
```